# C# System.BadImageFormatException for 32bit - 64bit

Tags: c#, dll, 32bit-64bit

I'm working with an application that uses 2 library, the first is stored outside of my project under c:\windows\system32 folder and it is used with:

```
[DllImport("FWLIB32.dll", EntryPoint="cnc_settimeout")]
public static extern short cnc_settimeout( ushort FlibHndl, int a );
```

The second one is imported in the Project references.

I need to use both of them, but if I config Visual studio to compile it with platform: "Any CPU" (and prefer 32bit) the first works and the second doesn't work, id I set platform x86 the second works but not the first.

In both cases it is thrown **System.BadImageFormatException**.
How to work with both dll? Is it possibile?

This is the first dll details:

```
PE details
Date compiled:  Thu, July 21, 2011, 10:19:34 PM
Linker version: 6.0
Machine type:   Intel 386 or later processors and compatible processors
PE format:  PE32

Characteristics:    Dynamic-link library
DLL Characteristics:    None
Subsystem:  The Windows graphical user interface (GUI) subsystem

Min OS: Windows 95
Min OS version: 4.0
Subsystem version:  4.0
File version:   0.0

Manifest:   No
Images: No
Icons:  No

Dialogs:    Unknown (Not implemented)
String tables:  Unknown (Not implemented)
Accelerators:   Unknown (Not implemented)
Cursors:    Unknown (Not implemented)
Menu:   Unknown (Not implemented)
More details
designedFor:    32-bit Windows
typeOfFile: DLL
fileVersion:    5.9.0.1
productVersion: 5.9.0.1

Comments:   DCompanyName
CompanyName:    FANUC CORPORATION
FileDescription:    Data Window Library for Win32
FileVersion:    5, 9, 0, 1
InternalName:   Fwlib32
LegalCopyright: Copyright (C) 1996-2011 FANUC CORPORATION
LegalTrademarks:    @OriginalFilename
OriginalFilename:   Fwlib32.dll
PrivateBuild:   TProductName
ProductName:    FANUC Data Window Library
```

This is the second one details:

```
PE details    
Date compiled:  Fri, December 7, 2012, 9:25:47 AM
Linker version: 10.0
Machine type:   x64
PE format:  PE32+

Characteristics:    Application can handle > 2GB addresses (Large address aware); Dynamic-link library
DLL Characteristics:    Image is NX compatible (No eXecute)
Subsystem:  The Windows graphical user interface (GUI) subsystem

Min OS: Windows XP 64-Bit Edition / Windows Server 2003 / Windows Server 2003 R2
Min OS version: 5.2
Subsystem version:  5.2
File version:   0.0

Manifest:   Yes (406 bytes)
Images: No
Icons:  Yes (2 icons)

Dialogs:    Unknown (Not implemented)
String tables:  Unknown (Not implemented)
Accelerators:   Unknown (Not implemented)
Cursors:    Unknown (Not implemented)
Menu:   Unknown (Not implemented)
More details
designedFor:    32-bit Windows on Windows NT
typeOfFile: DLL
fileVersion:    4.0.0.0
productVersion: 4.0.0.0

CompanyName:    Siemens
FileDescription:    Rpc Sinumerik Assembly
FileVersion:    4.0.0.0
InternalName:   Siemens.Sinumerik.Rpc.dll
LegalCopyright: Copyright (C) 2012
OriginalFilename:   RpcSinum.dll
```

For me are both 32bit... but Why the first one works only with "Any CPU" option?

Comment: This seems to be a dead end

Comment: The documentation of this question is backwards.  An OCX is very rarely available in 64-bit, c:\windows\system32 stores 64-bit components.  Contact the vendor of the first one and ask for the 32-bit version.  If you get no help then using a surrogate is a possible workaround.

Comment: Very bad news! I add some PE details

Comment: @HansPassant i'm not really sure this is an OCX... I edited my question. The only thing I know is that they are dll and I can use them separately

Comment: Contact Siemens for support, they can get you a 32-bit version.

Comment: You're right there is no answer, I had to change the second DLL